# Median, Circmcentre, Altitude

Tags: geometry

I got this question recently, and have been unable to solve it.

> $O$ is the circumcentre of $\Delta ABC$. $M$ is the midpoint of the median through $A$. Extend $OM$ to $N$ such that $OM=MN$. Prove that $N$ lies on the altitude through $A$.

My attempt:

Take $ME||BC$. Let it intersect $AN$ at $K$. Draw $OL\perp MK$. Now I merely need to prove that $\Delta LOM\cong\Delta KNM$. I already have $OM=MN$ and $\angle LMO=\angle KMN$. So now I need just one more criterion to prove them congruent and thus solve the question, but I have been unable to do so.

Please help. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try proving that $OD||AN$?

Comment: I have been unable to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The bisector of $BC$ and the altitude through $A$ are parallel lines and the bisector contains $O$.

Comment: But how do I show that $N$ lies on the altitude through $A$?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you very much!!!